# Beginner PHP: Mail() Function not Working

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail

I am new to php so please bear with me. I have created a registration for a test website which I am creating. The website collects user information and then sends a confirmation email. So far, no email has arrived after several attempts. I have tried the spam folder, yet to no avail.

Here is my code:

```
$to = "$email";
    // Change this to your site admin email
    $from = "someperson@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Complete your registration";
    //Begin HTML Email Message where you need to change the activation URL inside
    $message = '<html>
    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    Hi ' . $username . ',
    <br /><br />
    You must complete this step to activate your account with us.
    <br /><br />
    Please click here to activate now &gt;&gt;
    <a href="http://testw.freevar.com/activation.php?id=' . $id . '">
    ACTIVATE NOW</a>
    <br /><br />
    Your Login Data is as follows: 
    <br /><br />
    E-mail Address: ' . $email . ' <br />
    Password: ' . $password . ' 
    <br /><br /> 
    Thanks! 
    </body>
    </html>';
    // end of message
    $headers = "From: $from\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $to = "$to";
    // Finally send the activation email to the member
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers,-f $from);
```

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I have read online about a php.ini folder. I am creating a website from scratch and do not know what this is or if its necessary. Also, I am using a free hosting service which does not have an email address. I am not sure if this affects it.

Comment: Do you have access to any error logs that might tell you what went wrong?

Comment: Do you happen to be testing this with a server running on Windows? Also, what is that `-f` before the last parameter of `mail()`? You can't have that there. You already have the from address in `$headers` anyway.

Comment: My first question is, where is $to defined? I see `$to = $to` and `$to = $email` but what is `$email`?

Comment: What is the "-f" in your mailfunction? And where is $email set?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As comments point out, your code doesn't define `$to` properly and has syntax errors.

---

Make sure your SMTP server is configured correctly. This is the server used to send (and receive but not applicable) emails and the location of it will probably be written somewhere in the help/FAQ section of your hosting service, if they supply one.

The php.ini *file* is used to define environment variables for the PHP server, such as the location of the SMTP server. These settings can also be configured from within PHP with

```
ini_set('SMTP', 'smtp.example.com');
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'user@example.com');
ini_set('smtp_port','25');
```

Modifying the domain name, user email and port number as described by your host provider.

Comment: A couple of years ago I remember spending such a long time trying to figure out why the `mail()` function wasn't working until I found out this nasty **sendmail_from** setting :) cheers!